# Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:/// while fetching imageUrl in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am facing this error: Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:/// and unable to solved. Need some help from experts
Here how I am fetching the image url

```
Future<String> getProfileData() async {
    try {
      await apiBaseHelper.getAPICall(getUserData, {}).then((getData) async => {
            if (getData.containsKey('data'))
              {
                profileImg = getData["data"]["file"]["url"],
                setState(() {}),
              }
          });
    } catch (e) {
      print("something went wrong");
    }
    return profileImg;
  }
```

And then I am calling the function in initState

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getProfileData().then((value) => {
          profileImg = value.toString(),
          print(profileImg),
        });
    _pageController = PageController(initialPage: _selectedIndex);
  }
```

And then using as this

```
 Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border(
                        top: BorderSide(
                          width: 3,
                          color: _selectedIndex == 3
                              ? colors.primary
                              : Colors.transparent,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    width: 50,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(profileImg),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Declared the profileImg as:

```
String profileImg = "";
```

EDIT: 1

getAPICallFunction is as follows:

```
Future<dynamic> getAPICall(Uri apiEndPoint, Map<String, Object> param) async {
    // print("In get api");
    // print(apiEndPoint);
    var responseJson;

    try {
      final finalUri = apiEndPoint.replace(queryParameters: param); //USE THIS
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

      String? loginToken = prefs.getString(token);
      final response = await get(finalUri, headers: {
        "Authorization": 'Bearer ${loginToken}',
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }).timeout(const Duration(seconds: timeOut));
      // print("param****$param****$finalUri");
      // print("respon****${response.statusCode}");

      responseJson = _response(response);
      // print("responjson****$responseJson");
    } on SocketException {
      throw FetchDataException('No Internet connection');
    } on TimeoutException {
      throw FetchDataException('Something went wrong, try again later');
    }

    return responseJson;
  }
```

EDIT : 2
Issue got fixed just did this

```
backgroundImage: profileImg == "" ? null : NetworkImage(profileImg),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `responseJson = _response(response);` to `responseJson = response.body;`

or copy paste this code instead :

```
Future<dynamic> getAPICall(Uri apiEndPoint, Map<String, Object> param) async {
    // print("In get api");
    // print(apiEndPoint);
    var responseJson;

    try {
      final finalUri = apiEndPoint.replace(queryParameters: param); //USE THIS
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

      String? loginToken = prefs.getString(token);
      final response = await get(finalUri, headers: {
        "Authorization": 'Bearer ${loginToken}',
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }).timeout(const Duration(seconds: timeOut));
      // print("param****$param****$finalUri");
      // print("respon****${response.statusCode}");

      responseJson = response.body;
      // print("responjson****$responseJson");
    } on SocketException {
      throw FetchDataException('No Internet connection');
    } on TimeoutException {
      throw FetchDataException('Something went wrong, try again later');
    }

    return responseJson;
  }
```

Comment: I have Added the `getAPICall` functions. Please see it if is helps

Comment: I edited the answer try it if works